# moving rails2 to 4 and getting error - undefined method `with_scope'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.2

How to replace this Query in rails4.1.9

```
   AuditArea.send(query_options[:include_retired] ? :with_exclusive_scope :  :with_scope) {

     # some stuff
  }
```

Getting Error undefined method `with_scope' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with_scope` is now called **`scoping`** in the newer Rails versions. `with_exclusive_scope` should now be **`unscoped`**. Both methods accept a block so your code should work OK with them.

See docs for [`scoping`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-scoping) and [`unscoped`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped) for more info.

**Update:** the `scoping` method does not work if called on the class itself. It has to be called already on a scope (as opposed to `unscoped` which works on a bare model class). I would first add the "harmless" scope `all` (which selects all records and thus behaves the same way as the bare model class `AuditArea`) to the select so that both variants of the `send` work:

```
AuditArea.all.send(query_options[:include_retired] ? :unscoped : :scoping) {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: unscoped works but scoping still gives error * NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `scoping' for

Comment: Can you paste the full error? `scoping` **is** a [defined method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L290) in Rails 4.1.9.

Comment: *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `scoping' for #<Class:0x00000008174410>

Comment: Thanks for the help